# Is there a name for the relationship between matching combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a term that describes the relationship between $\binom 3 1 = \binom 3 2$ or $\binom 5 2 = \binom 5 3$? Symmetric comes to mind, but I was wondering if a specific term is used to describe these matching pairs.

Comment: Symmetry might be the best way to put it. Phrased most generally, $\dbinom{n}{m} = \dbinom{n}{n-m}$. As an off-the-hand tidbit: this is a surprisingly useful identity and comes up in geometry in an unexpected way.

Comment: It is just the definition of the binomial coefficient:

${n \choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!\cdot (n-k)!}$ Index-shift:

$n-k=i \Rightarrow k=n-i$

${n \choose {n-i}}=\frac{n!}{(n-i)!\cdot i!}={n \choose {i}}=$

Comment: The identity is obvious from taking complements in the "n choose k" combinatorial definition...

Comment: @DVD Yes, I'm aware. What I do not know is if this identity has a *name*. It chooses the complementary set, but is it referred to as a complement?

Comment: It's probably too elementary to have a name. It follows from the symmetry of the binomial coefficients and Pascal triangle...